# AWS SAM CLI local invoke account id not set when --profile is passed as parameter

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sam-cli

I'm trying to execute aws sam local invoke command in order to test my function locally. The problem occurs when I run this command passing **profile** parameter. The execution container sets account id as a dummy account like **123456789012**

Does anybody knows If there is any thing cached here? When I deploy my project using `sam deploy --guided` everything runs perfect and code is uploaded to AWS

my **~/.aws/config** and **~/.aws/credentials** files are filled

**credentials**

```sh
[adm]
aws_access_key_id=XXXXXXXXXXXXXx
aws_secret_access_key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

**config**

```sh
[adm]
region = eu-west-1
output = json
```

```sh
➜  POC sam local invoke "ScheduleBusinessRuleFunction"  --profile adm
Invoking scheduleBusinessRule (go1.x)
Skip pulling image and use local one: amazon/aws-sam-cli-emulation-image-go1.x:rapid-1.18.1.

Mounting /run/media/urkob/projects/Projects/POC/.aws-sam/build/ScheduleBusinessRuleFunction as /var/task:ro,delegated inside runtime container
START RequestId: bc99de19-290b-46fa-908a-744d54547cbe Version: $LATEST
operation error CloudWatch Events: PutTargets, https response error StatusCode: 400, RequestID: 8e335486-de38-49bb-a06e-8090e26e9628, api error AccessDeniedException: Access to the resource arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:123456789012:function:POC-executeBusinessRule is denied. Reason: Adding cross-account target is not permitted.: OperationError
null
END RequestId: bc99de19-290b-46fa-908a-744d54547cbe
REPORT RequestId: bc99de19-290b-46fa-908a-744d54547cbe  Init Duration: 0.14 ms  Duration: 1415.60 ms    Billed Duration: 1500 ms        Memory Size: 128 MB    Max Memory Used: 128 MB
{"errorMessage":"operation error CloudWatch Events: PutTargets, https response error StatusCode: 400, RequestID: 8e335486-de38-49bb-a06e-8090e26e9628, api error AccessDeniedException: Access to the resource arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:123456789012:function:POC-executeBusinessRule is denied. Reason: Adding cross-account target is not permitted.","errorType":"OperationError"}%                                                                                                          
➜  POC
```

**UPDATED: 21/02/16**
I've been searching what could be the problem. I'm using aws-sdk-go-v2 the example they exposed in ther official github documentation to get an instance of configuration:

I tryied two ways of getting config instance as you can see in this piece of code, the line commented and the line that comes after that is not commented.

```golang
import (
    "context"

    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/config"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/service/cloudwatchevents"
)

//NewCloudWatchService scheduler service
func NewCloudWatchService() CWEPutEventsAPI {
    cfg, err := config.LoadDefaultConfig(context.TODO())
    //Happens the same in local with this line
    // cfg, err := config.LoadDefaultConfig(context.TODO(), config.WithSharedConfigFiles(config.DefaultSharedCredentialsFiles))
    if err != nil {
        panic("configuration error, " + err.Error())
    }

    return cloudwatchevents.NewFromConfig(cfg)
}
```

This is my **template.yaml** file. I'm developing usin AWS SAM yaml templates. As you can see I reference **ExecuteLambda** in **ScheduleLambda** using `GettAtt` method but when the code runs in local the region and accountId are always the same: default values.

```yaml
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Globals:
  Function:
    Timeout: 5


Resources:
  ScheduleBusinessRuleFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      FunctionName: POC-scheduleBusinessRule
      CodeUri: functions/scheduleBusinessRule/
      Handler: scheduleBusinessRule
      Runtime: go1.x
      MemorySize: 128
      Timeout: 10
      Tracing: Active
      Role: !GetAtt SchedulerRole.Arn
      Environment:
        Variables:
          LAMBDA_ARN: !GetAtt ExecuteBusinessRuleFunction.Arn
          EVENT_BUS: "default"

  ExecuteBusinessRuleFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      FunctionName: POC-executeBusinessRule
      CodeUri: functions/executeBusinessRule/
      Handler: executeBusinessRule
      Runtime: go1.x
      MemorySize: 128
      Tracing: Active
```

Comment: It [used to be the case](https://github.com/aws/aws-sam-cli/issues/210) that you had to `export AWS_SDK_LOAD_CONFIG=true`.

Comment: I tryied adding this env var but It didn't work. I think the problem is related with `aws-sdk-go-v2` and **sam local**